# Android Push notifications not working when app is closed

Tags: android, push-notification, android-8.0-oreo, server-sent-events

I'm using [OkSse](https://github.com/heremaps/oksse) to subscribe to my Server Sent Events.

Whenever a new message is sent by the server, a notification should appear whether the app is in **foreground,minimized or fully closed**.

The notifications work as expected when *minimized or in foreground* but when **fully closed**, this only works on some **device brands**.

Researching a [bit](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/why-your-push-notifications-never-see-the-light-of-day-3fa297520793), I found that:

> this issue is noticed only on phones by manufacturers like Xiaomi,
>   Oppo, One Plus, Vivo, Lenovo, Huawei, Samsung, and a few others.

How does `WhatsApp, Facebook, Slack, Gmail, etc..` display notifications even if app is closed?

I don't use `FCM`, just subscribe to `Sse`.

I also have in manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<receiver android:name="com.goparty.communication.NotificationsAlarmReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.media.action.DISPLAY_NOTIFICATION" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

How can I achieve this?

### Update

I managed to make it work by using an `IntentService` and `BroadcastReceiver` but this crashes for `Oreo` versions.

After more [reading](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/JobIntentService) I found that `JobIntentService` is the replacement of `IntentService` when targeting `Android O` and above.

The transition to `JobIntentService` was pretty straight forward but again, my solution is not working when I close the app.

The whole purpose of notifications are to work even when the app is closed.

Using `IntentService` worked in the background by sending a `broadcast` with a new intent of my service.

I'm doing the same with `JobIntentService` with no luck.

Here's my code:

```
public class NotificationService extends JobIntentService {

    private static final int JOB_ID = 1;
    private NotificationManager notificationManager;

    public static void enqueueWork(Context context, Intent intent) {
        enqueueWork(context, NotificationService.class, JOB_ID, intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Logger.logGoParty(getClass().getSimpleName() + "#onCreate");
        notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Logger.logGoParty("Running in background.");
        sendBroadcast(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NotificationService.class));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleWork(@NonNull Intent intent) {
        Logger.logGoParty(getClass().getSimpleName() + "#onHandleWork");
        Logger.logGoParty("Sse initialized");

        Request request = new Request.Builder().url("the sse url").build();
        OkSse okSse = new OkSse();

        ServerSentEvent sse = okSse.newServerSentEvent(request, new ServerSentEvent.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void onOpen(ServerSentEvent sse, Response response) {
                Logger.logGoParty(response.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onMessage(ServerSentEvent sse, String id, String event, String message) {
                Logger.logGoParty("Sse#onMessage: " + message);
                try {
                    JSONObject promoJson = new JSONObject(message);

                    sendNotification(...);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Logger.logGoParty("JSONException: " + e.toString());
                }
            }
                // ...
        });
    }

    private void sendNotification(String promoImageUrl, String notificationContent, String title) {

        try {
            URL url = new URL(promoImageUrl);
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());


            NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle style = new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle();
            style.bigPicture(bitmap);

            Uri defaultSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MapsActivity.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
            intent.putExtra("page-to-open", "promotions");
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);


            NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, GoParty.PROMO_CHANNEL_ID)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round)
                    .setContentTitle(title)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setSound(defaultSound)
                    .setContentText(notificationContent)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .setStyle(style)
                    .setLargeIcon(bitmap)
                    .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                    .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                    .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_MESSAGE);

            notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());

            Log.i("GoParty", "Notification sent ----- ");

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Logger.logGoParty(e.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Logger.logGoParty(e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Notification Receiver:

```
public class NotificationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, NotificationService.class);
        NotificationService.enqueueWork(context, notificationIntent);
    }
}
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.goparty">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />


    <application
        android:name=".scopes.application.GoParty"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
            android:name=".MapsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.goparty.LoginActivity" />
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name=".jobs.NotificationService"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" />

        <receiver android:name=".receivers.NotificationReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: after android 6.0 you should use NotificAION CHANNAL  to get pushnotification

Comment: can you refer server-side code?

Comment: @MuhaiminurRahman Upated question with code.

Comment: WhatsApp, Facebook, Slack, Gmail all using FCM service(Firebasemessagingservice)

Comment: have you tried using ONBIND() method of service.

Comment: Try to split your problem in two parts. Firstly ensure that your NotificationReceivers `onReceive()` is called (e.g. put log there). If yes, than the problem is in your NotificationService, if not, then you need to investigate NotificationReceiver.

Answer (score 2):

Your Approach: Using OkSse for notification means the need of ever running background service.

Problem 1: Android background service restrictions [link](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background#services)

[JobIntentService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/JobIntentService.html) internally will use JobService and it will not be a continues running service. It will not run indifferently as execution time limit will apply. It will stop and rescheduled to continue its execution later. So in your case, it will not work.

Problem 2: Devices Xiaomi, Oppo, One Plus, Vivo, Lenovo, Huawei, Samsung have Battery Optimization check which lets JobIntentService to stop.

Solution:

1) Run Foreground service which is ugly and not recommended

2) Firebase High Priority Notification [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#setting-the-priority-of-a-message) HIGHLY RECOMMENDED

I have implemented it on the above mention devices, even if the app is set to battery optimization mode you will receive a notification.

Comment: so we are BOUND to use Firebase if we want this functionality? That sucks!